# Python OGR: Filter Shapefiles by Lat Long and Export To CSV

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

Using osgeo's Python API for OGR, I'd like to implement the following process:

1. Import ESRI Shapefiles from a given directory (call it `input_dir`)
2. Import a CSV file that contains lat-longs of interest (call it `poicsv`)
3. Join the CSV file long, lats with the Shapefile layer and extract the feature attribute values for that long, lat

I am currently up to the step where I have a single Shapefile loaded, and the CSV file loaded with long/lats in a list of tuples (ie. [(-123.76073, 41.24946), (-123.84451, 41.24946), ...]). Per long lat, I am trying to use SetSpatialFilter on the layer by the following code:

```
for ll in longlat:
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint_2D(ll[0], ll[1])
    layer.SetSpatialFilter(point)
    for feat in layer:
        feat.items()
```

However, upon sanity checking I've noticed there is no API for removing the Spatial Filter in my for loop, and I am also concerned about the memory leak created by creating a wkbPoint through the ogr.Geometry function in every iteration. Will the point object be cleaned up every iteration, and how could I reset the Spatial Filter every iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `point` geom will get cleaned up automatically by Python's garbage collector each iteration after it goes out of scope.  I just tested by running a 10 million iteration loop and creating a point and overwriting the same variable and memory usage stayed the same.

According to the [documentation](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Layer-class.html#SetSpatialFilter), you can reset your spatial filter by passing a NULL value (`None` in Python), i.e.

```
layer.SetSpatialFilter(None)
```

Though I don't think you actually need to as you're overwriting the existing spatial filter with a new one each iteration.